# What is the purpose of Ruby's Numeric's Rectangular method?

Tags: ruby, numeric

So, I called methods on an integer (I was looking to see if divisible_by? was in core ruby. It's not.) and saw this method called rectangular. When I called it on 5, it returned [5, 0]. I went and [looked it up](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-rectangular). Sure enough, it takes a number, and returns [number, 0]. What is the purpose of this method?

Comment: As for your `divisible_by?` question, `10.divisible_by?(5)` is equivalent to `10.modulo(5).zero?` or shorter `10 % 5 == 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method is defined on `Numeric` (which is the parent class of all number classes, including `Integer`, `Float` and also `Complex`.

Now, `Complex` is the only class which overrides this method. For complex numbers, [it returns](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Complex.html#method-i-rect) an array containing the real part and the imaginary part. For all real numbers (that is, all the other `Numeric` types), the imaginary part is always 0.

The method is called `rectangle` or `rect` because complex numbers describe a vector in the two-dimensional space which can be visualized as a rectangle in a graph.

To learn more about complex numbers, have a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) on this mathematical topic.